# Determain the Height of a TabRow in a TabControl (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage, multirow

i have a WinForms [TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which is set to

```
Multiline = True
```

I made my own custom RowsChanged Event

```
''' <summary>
''' Event that is raised if the rowCount of the control changed.
''' </summary>
Public Event RowsChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

Private Sub Me_SizeChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged, Me.SelectedIndexChanged, Me.ControlAdded, Me.ControlRemoved
    If rows <> Me.RowCount Then
        rows = Me.RowCount
        RaiseEvent RowsChanged(sender, e)
    End If
End Sub
```

Now I can register to that event. I want to know, the height of one row, so I can do some size calculation. Is there any way to determain that? So far I just counted pixel, which isn't quite nice.

Comment: Use the TabControl.GetTabRect() method to find out where tabs are located.  GetTabRect(0).Height gets you the row height.

Comment: @HansPassant: tested `GetTabRect` approach - this is the solution. Please post as an answer.

Comment: @HansPassant: I can second what Neolisk says. Please add your solution as an answer. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comment, you can use the TabControl.GetTabRect() method to retrieve the bounds of a tab at runtime.  Beware that it may change on a Multiline tab control as the user navigates the tabs and rows swap position.